# Android: HttpGet not posting to Database

Tags: java, android, asp.net, database, get

I'm simply trying to send data to a database as proof of concept. I currently have an ASP page that will send data there for me. I have an extremely basic Android app set to post the information to the database, but none of the data is posting there. I'm not getting any errors or force closes and the url is the proper url and format to send to the database with that particular ASP file.

Here is my code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //set url
            String url = "**removed for security reasons**";
            url += "var1=" + editVar1.getText().toString() + "&var2=" + editVar2.getText().toString() + "&var3=" + editVar3.getText().toString();

            //display url in toast
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            //prepare connection
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

            //send HttpGet
            try
            {
                client.execute(request);
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just to notify you, network operations should be executed in the background (as asynctask or intentService).
Secondly you should not use GET for writing stuff in database.
You should use POST and not GET:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var1", editVar1.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var2",editVar2.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var3",editVar3.getText().toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: I understand I should use POST and not GET, but for what I'm doing I wanted more of a proof of concept and what I was given was an ASP page using the GET method as a way to pass information.

Comment: Literally all I'm asking is if there is anything wrong with this code. I will probably later on change this to a POST, but for the simple effort of getting this type of database connection going, this is the method I've been told to go with.

Comment: Running the entire process on a background thread solved my problem.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code actually, it can be done this way as well. But newer versions of SDK require that all code related to network activites should not be part of main thread as they could make app non responsive.

Comment: Yeah, I worked that out. It's just weird that it never caused a force close and also didn't do the task until I moved it to a different thread. I've done texting that had to be done in a background thread, but it caused a force close even though it still worked.

Comment: Yeah that is weird, usually network task in main thread causes exception to be thrown...